# Accessing Map Tiles of MKMapView

Tags: ios, iphone, maps, apple-maps

I'm currently developing an app that needs to display a map of where the user is currently located in the world. For technical reasons, I need to access every map tiles as an image (png/jpg) before going in the rendering pipeline.

I have tried 3rd party services like MapBox, MapQuest as they have a REST api that enables me to receive a png/jpg of a tile according to the requested location. The issue here is that MapBox isn't free, so I was wondering if there was a way to access the tiles that Apple provides in it's maps app. What service are they using under the hood? Would I be violating some terms of use by going with this approach.

Please note that using some integrated "do-it-all" UIMapView is not an option for me, I need the image directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google has a REST API.  You can see the details here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1.  It does cost money if you go over the usage limits.

I manually download Map Tiles for my app, but I don't use MKMapKit.  I have my own MapView and I am using a combination of MapBox, Thunderforest, CalTopo, OSM, and map tiles that I generated and host on AWS.  All of them have a pretty easy map tile URL scheme, but you do have to pay for most of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google's terms of use doesn't allow me to do what I do with the tiles afterward. I'm glad you answered tho because you made me discover Thunderforest which didn't pop up in my search for a map tile provider. Would you say Thunderforest is reliable?

Comment: Thunderforest has been very reliable for me.  The one problem I have had is that it is slower than the other services.  If you are interested in Thunderforest this map may interest you once it comes out https://www.mapbox.com/blog/vector-terrain-outdoors/

Comment: How can I set WMS tiles layer at MapBox in Swift like Google provided some methods to add it at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles, thanks in advance